# Extract infomation from Google Calendar

Tags: html, json, api, google-calendar-api, icalendar

Looking for a way to retrieve event entries placed into google calendar and display it in basic HTML format. much like using openweathermap api that offers Json feed i would like something similar, any suggestions ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has Calendar API, you can use that. I'm using it on my website to sync events, and it works flawlessly. You can find more info at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/.